# I need help understanding the proper usage of "pointer to array of n integers" initialization

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion

The following declaration:

**`int (*x)[10]`**

is defined as **x is an integer pointer to an integer array of 10 elements**.

**Question 1** : Doesn't this mean that **x** initially points to the first element of an array of 10 integers? If so, then, how is this different from the simple **`int x[10]`**?

**Question 2** : If **`int (*x)[10]`** is different, then how is it different and what are some instances of its practical usage?

**Question 3** : I was trying to write a simple program access, write to and print the array elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int (*x)[12], i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 11;)
    {
        (*x)[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", (*x)[i++]);
    }
}
```

I keep getting a **segmentation fault** when I run it. I understand that a segmentation fault occurs when I try to access memory that I don't have access to. But I am only accessing the 12 elements that I have initialized. Then why does my program exit with a segmentation fault? Also, am I accessing the array (**`(*x)[i] = i`**) correctly and are there other ways to access it?

Comment: Which part in your learning material makes you assume they could be somehow the same? A pointer holds an address. An array holds multiple members. A pointer to an array holds the address of an array what contains multiple members.

Comment: "x is an integer pointer to an integer array of 10 elements" Rather: x is a pointer to an array of 10 integer elements.

Comment: "I was trying to write a simple program access, write to and print the array elements" There is no array in your program so you can't do that. In order to use a point to an array, you need an array to point at. You cannot "store data inside pointers", that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin I got confused by the [10] part. I assumed that (*x)[10] would automatically allocate memory for a 10 integer element array and x would point to its base address.

Comment: "I assumed that (*x)[10] would automatically allocate memory for a 10 integer element array and x would point to its base address" How would that be different from `int x[10]` then? Because what you just described is the behavior of an ordinary array, which decays into a pointer to its first element when used in an expression.

Comment: @Gerhardh When we do int x[10]; int *x_ptr; x_ptr = x; Then it means that x is pointing to the base element of array x. I got confused by int (*x)[10], because I assumed it allocates a 10 element array that isn't named and then x would point to its base address. I was wrong though, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be decalred like

```
int main( void )
```

In the shown program you declared an uninitialized pointer

```
int (*x)[12], i;
```

that has an indeterminate value. So dereferencing the pointer

```
(*x)[i] = i;
```

results in undefined behavior.

Instead you could write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 12 };
    int a[N];

    int (*x)[N] = &a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        (*x)[i] = i;
        printf( "%d\n", (*x)[i] );
    }
}
```

Though the program will look simpler if to write it like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 12 };
    int a[N];

    int *x = a;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        x[i] = i;
        printf( "%d\n", x[i] );
    }
}
```

In this declaration

```
int *x = a;
```

is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.

In this declaration

```
int (*x)[N] = &a;
```

the initializing expression `&a` is already a pointer of the type `int ( * )[N]`.

So in the expression

```
(*x)[i] = i;
```

the subexpression `*x` yields lvalue of the array `a`. So in fact the above expression is equivalent to

```
a[i] = i;
```

Pay attention to that in the both declarations

```
int *x = a;
```

and

```
int ( *x )[N] = &a;
```

the pointers `x` store the starting address of the memory extent occupied by the array `a` but have different types. Dereferencing the first pointer you will get the first element of the array `a`. Dereferencing the second pointer you will get the whole array itself.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that the first program is an overtly convoluted way of doing something simple and should be avoided?

Comment: @limbo1927 Of course the second program is more clear and simpler.